# How to re-ask a user for input when they input wrong data the first time

Tags: python-3.x

I am checking to make sure that the zoo can let a ship travel with animals, in order to do this the closest person to the zoo must be at least 60 meters away due to safety reasons. I am using the code below

```
#Ask them how far away the closest person is from the ship 
while True:
    try:
        Distance = int(input("How far away is the closest person 
from the ship? (in meters) "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    else:
        break
if Distance <=60:
    print("Please ask them to move away")
else:
    print("People are at a safe distance")
```

I want to make it so that the question re-asks when they put in a distance that is too low, so then they can check again and put in the new distance 
I want it to look like :

```
How far away is the closest person from the ship (in meters)? 8
Please ask them to move away
How far away is the closest person from the ship (in meters)? 789
People are at a safe distance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `ask()` into a function. call it from an infinite loop. The loop would only `break` (stop calling `ask()`) if the `Distance` is > 60.

```
def ask():
  while True:
    try:
        Distance = int(input("How far away is the closest person from the ship? (in meters) "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        continue
    else:
        break
  return Distance

while True:
  if ask() <=60:
      print("Please ask them to move away")
  else:
      print("People are at a safe distance")
      break
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i use that and type in a letter instead of a number it crashes. Is there anyway it can be changed so it does what it's doing curently and doesn't have the traceback error come up

Comment: yep,  just include your previous code. I edited the code to do so.

Comment: @M.Nor I meant to include that the first time. did it work for you?

Comment: @M.Nor if this answer or any other answer help you solve the problem then please mark it as the solution. so if fellow programmers can find the solution easier if they run into the same problem in the future, thanks.

Comment: i dont know how to do that @OLIVER.KOO